# Error installing ionic using npm on windows7

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm

I'm running the following command to install ionic using npm

```
npm install -g ionic
```

Getting the following error:

```
86790 verbose stack Error: node-sass@3.4.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
86790 verbose stack Exit status 1
86790 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:239:16)
86790 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
86790 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
86790 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
86790 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
86790 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
86790 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
86790 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)
86791 verbose pkgid node-sass@3.4.2
86792 verbose cwd C:\Program Files\Console2
86793 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
86794 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic"
86795 error node v6.1.0
86796 error npm  v3.8.6
86797 error code ELIFECYCLE
86798 error node-sass@3.4.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
86798 error Exit status 1
86799 error Failed at the node-sass@3.4.2 postinstall script 'node scripts/build.js'.
86799 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
86799 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
86799 error not with npm itself.
86799 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
86799 error     node scripts/build.js
86799 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
86799 error     npm bugs node-sass
86799 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
86799 error     npm owner ls node-sass
86799 error There is likely additional logging output above.
86800 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I'm also getting an error relating to python above this error. Does anyone have any ideas? I'm new to node and ionic.

Comment: What is your node version?

Comment: @James_Parsons v6.1.0

Comment: could it be related to your node version?

Comment: @James_Parsons Should I downgrade to the LTS version?

Comment: I would try, I've had similar issues with Ionic where I could only get it to run on 4.0.0

Comment: @James_Parsons That worked.